# Checking if src of img contains certain text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to use jQuery [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to run through each image on a page and check if the src tag contains a certain http value.  How would I run a check on the text in the src attribute with jQuery or javacript.  I have the overview of what I am attempting below:

```
$('img').each(function(i){
  var img = $(this),
      imgSrc = img.attr('src'),
      siteURL = "http://url.com";

  if(!imgSrc.contains(siteURL)){
     imgSrc = siteURL + imgSrc;
  }
});
```

I have a feeling regex may be the way to go just don't know how for sure.

Comment: Just so you know [$.contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) Is not for strings, it is for elements. You check if one element is contained within another, not if a string is contained within another.

Comment: Thank you @Chad, yes I realize i posted the wrong link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// find all img's without the siteURL, and add it
$('img:not([src^="http://url.com"])').each(function(i){
  this.src = siteURL + this.src;
});
```

Comment: This ended up doing the trick, thank you.  And looks most effective and simple way to get the task done.

Comment: It may be simplier but I would think that not putting the load on the selector and instead using the method @Nicola Peluchetti mentioned (except remove `var img = $(this), imgSrc = img.attr('src')` and replace it with just `var imgSrc = this.src` to get a more efficient solution).

Answer (score 6):

i'd do (using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)):

```
$('img').each(function(i){
      var imgSrc = this.src;
      var siteURL = "http://url.com";

  if(imgSrc.indexOf(siteURL) === -1){
     imgSrc = siteURL + imgSrc;
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 I would change `var img = $(this), imgSrc = img.attr('src')` to `var imgSrc = this.src` it isn't necessary to warp it in a jQuery object.

Comment: Yes you are right i updated my answer including your suggestion.

Comment: fyi you're introducing a global here (siteURL)

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply make a selector to do that?

```
 $('img[src*="http://url.com"]')
```

That should select just the elements with that text in the src tag, without you having to write custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to search your `imgSrc` string if it has the `siteURL` string in it.

The `indexOf` method returns the position of the substring within the main string. If it's not found, it returns `-1`:

```
if (imgSrc.indexOf(siteURL) == -1) {
     imgSrc = siteURL + imgSrc;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at :contains() Selector.

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: There is an attibute contains selector also http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/